# Eclipse helios for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse

How can I install Eclipse Helios for Ubuntu 10.04? I downloaded the package eclipse-java-helios-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz, unzipped it and doubleclicked the icon eclipse. Nothing happened.

Comment: Did you try running `eclipse` from the command-line?  If so, what was the output?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it does not seem like the Helios version of Eclipse has an actual installation, you're just going to have to open the eclipse file (not the one with the icon, I believe) you wish to start it. You can install Galileo from the Ubuntu software center, and then if you want to install the CDT (C/C++) or the PDT (PHP), you can do that from the help menu.

Answer (score 1):

Just download the eclipse helios for linux from eclipse download site.extract it and double-click the diamond shape 'eclipse' icon.I got it like this for 32 bit system.